# Parsing error in Ionic Config file. Please make sure it is valid JSON

Tags: json, ionic-framework, ngcordova

All of a sudden, I'm getting this while trying to run ionic. What's wrong?

My Laptop Suddenly Crashes and when I restarted my System and Open Ionic in Code Editor it shows the Following Error:

```html
Unable to parse Ionic Config file. Please make sure it is valid JSON (.ionic/ionic.config)

Caught exception:
 SyntaxError: Unexpected token
    at Object.parse (native)
    at Object.module.exports.load (C:\Users\BBytes\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\lib\config.js:14:26)
    at Object.&lt;anonymous&gt; (C:\Users\BBytes\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\lib\utils\stats.js:31:31)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.&lt;anonymous&gt; (C:\Users\BBytes\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\lib\cli.js:3:18)

Mind letting us know? https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After Some trial and Error:

I think I have found the source of my problem!

My `C:/Users/{username}/.ionic/ionic.config` file was corrupted when my pc crashed /or due to some other error.

Weird that that file NEVER gets cleared when uninstalling ionic.

Just `Delete the file` and when you run `ionic serve` it will create the file by default in the folder.